# Tableau: List Projects > Workbooks > Views for an authenticated user

Tags: javascript, tableau-api

As an example, this URL contains a dozen or so projects: https://tableautest.domain.uk/t/CustomerSharing/view/projects

In each project there are several workbooks. Within each workbook there are several views. Some are Tableau reports and some are links to external sites

How can I display all this programatically whether using the JavaScript API or the REST API? I can authenticate against Tableau using the JavaScript API. What I would like next, is as I say (for the logged in user)

1. List of projects under https://tableautest.domain.uk/t/CustomerSharing/view/projects
2. When they go into a project on the site, it needs to display a list of workbooks for that project for that user for the above URL.
3. When they go into a workbook from (2) for it to show the links to views depending on the type of view it then redirects or inserts it into an iFrame

Please advise on the best way to go about doing this. If we could even get a list of Sites > Projects > Workbooks > Dashboard > Views, this would be much better!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I have recently used the Tableau Rest API and found it pretty useful while querying against a project or a workbook for it's details so I would suggest you take a look at [Tableau REST API reference](http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/api/rest_api/en-us/help.htm#REST/rest_api_ref.htm). It should help you solve problems 1 and 2 that you have stated.

I used [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) to confirm that I was getting the details I wanted and then continued development using the [Tableau REST API wrapper in Python](https://github.com/bryantbhowell/tableau_rest_api) (I have forked off this repo to support some functionality that was not available here).

Also, the REST API supports authentication against the server but I have used Admin permissions for all my interactions so user account authentication needs verification.

The 3rd problem you have stated seems like you would need to use the JavaScript API to load the view into an iFrame. You would need to set up Trusted Authentication on the Tableau server to be able to embed views. You can find more details [here](http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/server/en-us/trusted_auth_webURL.htm) and [here](http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/server/en-us/trusted_auth.htm).

Comment: Since this was over a year ago - all issues have been resolved :-)

Comment: Glad to hear, but the information might be useful for other people so I will leave it on. The down vote was unnecessary as this question did not have an answer and I only wanted to help.